# Trouble loading font-family locally

Tags: css, fonts, font-family

I'm currently loading my font-family from google's CDN like this:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

But I'm at the point where I need to load them locally in order to optimize my web speed. Here's what I've tried:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Inter;
    src:url("../fonts/Inter-Medium.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Inter;
    src:url("../fonts/Inter-Semibold.ttf");
}

body {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif !important;
}
```

But that isn't working as when loaded from google's cdn. I can see it works only for weight `500` but not when the weight is `600`. Some help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to load url directly in css from google cdn.

Comment: That's not the point.. I need to load them locally.

Comment: if you load them locally, you'll need a license and it may most likely slow down you load speed as you can only have so many requests to the same domain, also you will need all the different font formats to make it work in all the browsers

Comment: @Pete So I'm stuck with CDNs when talking about fonts?

Comment: no you can load them locally but just beware for each font you will be adding 5 extra requests (the stylesheet and the four different format fonts - eot, ttf, svg, woff and perhaps woff2), usually if you load it from cdns - it may be that the user has been to some other site that may already have downloaded those fonts so you could even save on a request there if their browser has already cached it.  Personally I think if your page is that slow that you are looking to move where fonts are loaded from, then there is a larger issue for you to worry about

Comment: offtopic but it's a great font (at least for english characters)...

Comment: Have you look in this page: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started ?

Answer (score 2):

I describe all the actions I have taken to successfully connect to the google font.

1. I downloaded [fonts.google.com](https://fonts.google.com/share?selection.family=Inter:wght@600) (Download button is at the top right) inside text `Download family`.
2. I added all the files to my project.[image]
3. I connected the file direction, HTML/CSS.

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: Name;
  src: url('Inter-VariableFont_slnt,wght.ttf');
}
p{
  font-family: Name;
}
```

```html
<p>TEST</p>
```

4. You can put any `name` instead of `name`.
5. And after that, everything worked.

Screen code:

[image]

that's how it was in the beginning:

[image]

so after:

[image]